# Unknown segfault - with simple reproduce-able example

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, glibc, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have this simple code which causes a segfault in initstate_r:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int *test[8];

    struct random_data rstate;
    char random_bin[256];
    initstate_r(1,random_bin,256,&rstate);

    test[0] = NULL;

    printf("%p",test[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

It does not produce a segfault if `int *test[8]` lines are removed.

It doesn't seem to cause a segfault on most linux systems, but it does on ubuntu linux subsystem for windows gcc (or maybe that is just luck)?

Is my use of initstate_r actually wrong and I just get lucky sometimes? I don't see anything wrong with it?

Thanks!

Comment: How can it even compile if you remove that line?

Comment: If i remove all the lines using test variable then by chance it was running OK because of the way the memory of the struct just happens to be initialised to null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the `initstate_r` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/random_r.3.html):

> Before calling this function, the `buf.state` field must be initialized to NULL.

You pass a pointer to the *uninitialized* structure `rstate`. That means all members of the structure will be uninitialized and have *indeterminate* values. If the `initstate_r` attempt to access these members then it could lead to *undefined behavior*.

You need to initialize at least the `state` member of the structure to a null pointer:

```
rstate.state = NULL;
```

Comment: aghhh I just realise this too, looked into the source code for saw first thing it does is read buf->state.....  :-(  Thank you! Shows that you need to RTFM carefully. I just glanced over it and read the details for initstate, and just assumed you gave initstate_r somewhere to write :-(  I guess this also explains why so many initstate_r examples use calloc()!